# View returning null

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask

Outline of my code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Client client;
MyImageView iv;
Bitmap b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyImageView iv = new MyImageView(this);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.untitled);
    iv=(MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);}
    iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.example.zooming.MyImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyImgaeView.java

```
MyImageView extends View {
    public MyImageView(Context ct){
       super(ct);
       //some other works
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
       new ConnectTask().execute("");
       }
     //Other code
     class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
         @Override
         public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {  
                iv=(MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                    return true;
         }

   }
   class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,Bitmap,Bitmap> 
   {
       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... message) {
               //some code to get the bitmap
               publishProgress(mybitmap);
       return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       iv=(MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
       if(iv==null)
           Log.i("Exception",ex.toString());
       iv.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
       }
   }

}
```

iv is always returning null in ConnectTask(AsynTask) while its working fine in MyGestureDetector...why?  also when i am making the ConnectTask the inner class of MainActivity then its working fine...!!

Comment: In asynctask you show "mybitmap" - but where you load bitmap into "mybitmap" ?

Comment: I'm starring at your code for a while now and just get more questions: Why do you instantiate `MyImageView()` in `onCreate()`?
Why do you call `findViewById` every time you need the view? Why not just in `onCreate()` once and store the reference? Why do you create a custom view in this case anyway? Please help to help us helping you (with help ...)

Comment: @jboi Because that MyImageView is giving me the whole functionality of pinch zooming sending messages to server which is running on java and getting messages . I just posted the part of my project in brief where something is going wrong.

Comment: @daro2189 i commented(not included) that part because i have tested that mybitmap have right value. just to make sure that post get more attention on problem.

Comment: add after this line "iv.setImageBitmap(values[0]);" - iv.postInvalidate();  ,maybe it will help

Comment: @jboi and i instantiate the MyImageView to pass the Context. Is there any other method..!!

Comment: @daro2189 actually setImageBitmap is calling invalidate itself...

Comment: @Begginer I doubt, that the instance returned by `findViewById` is the same as the one you instantiate. Did you go thru a tutorial? It's really interesting to check what happens here behind the scenes. 'I doubt' -> I'm also not sure. Maybe you can check that first. I would look in the meantime for the tutorial I used, when I tried this the first time - and add it to my answer

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your code - why you find image in "MyImageView"? I think you want to show image in "MyImageView" class? Could you add all code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `findViewById()` only once in the right context. Three ways you could achieve this with your code:

- Change Activity to contain your GestureListener and the AsynkTask as inner classes and reference the field `iv` of your Activity
- Keep GestureListener and AsynkTask as standalone classes and add the MyImageView as parameter to their constructor. Construct the two instances for this two classes in `onCreate()` after the `findViewById()`
- Put GestureListener and AsynkTask as inner classes of MyImageView and add MyImageView as parameter to their constructor. When constructing the two instances from within MyImage just pass `this`.

`findViewById()` is context sensitive. This means it searches for a view starting at the current context. If the current context is an Activity it searches thru the corresponding XML Layout. If the context is a view, it just searching from that view downwards. In your case there's a good chance that the `findViewById()` is searching down the view only for the id - and cant find it. I say 'a good chance' because IMO the one in `onDoubleTap()` should also not work.

EDIT:

When I created my first custom view, I used the tutorial provided by the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).
It also has a nice and helpful section about the context.

Comment: I solved the problem by taking one reference of MyImageView in and setting it from MainActivity setIv(MyImageView tiv){iv=tiv}... But still confused about why iv was working fine in MyGestureDetector and not in ConnectTask(even not in constructor of both ConnectTask and MyImageView).

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
MyImageView extends View {

    public MyImageView(Context ct){
       super(ct);

       //some other works
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

       //no it have to be in other place
       //new ConnectTask().execute("");
       }

//function which set image after task, of course you can in parameter set bitmap, string 
//or whatever you want

public void setImageInThread(int id_image){
   new ConnectTask().execute(id_image);
}


   class connectTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Bitmap> 
   {
       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Ingeter... message) {
               //some code to get the bitmap
             //  publishProgress(mybitmap);  do you really need this?
       //here you can load/decode image
       Bitmap bitmapa = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), message[0]);
       return bitmapa;
       }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap toShow) {
            if(toShow == null)
              return; //is error

            MyImageView.this.setImageBitmap(toShow);
        }


       /*@Override
       public void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       iv=(MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
       if(iv==null)
           Log.i("Exception",ex.toString());
       iv.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
       }*/
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i am receiving image from server so cant get ID.

Comment: There is no problem to change image id into string and load bitmap from url ;) but ok no problem